# How do I determine overexposed or underexposed Image using Java and correct it?

Tags: java, image-processing

I am doing my project "Face Replacement System" in Java.

For that I need to first check if an image is underexposed or overexposed, and brighten it or make it less bright respectively.

Is there a way to do this in Java?

Answer (score 2):

The Java Advanced Imaging API includes functionality to take a histogram. See the [JAI Programmer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-5413-10/806-5413-10.pdf). If the image is underexposed/overexposed, then you'll find most amplitudes "bunched" towards the lower/upper end of the histogram respectively rather than being more spread over the total range.

To brighten the image, have a look at the standard Java RescaleOp class.

The JAI also provides various enhancement functions, including "amplitude rescaling" (effectively, contrast enhancement).

Also have a look at the section in the JAI programmer's guide on Histogram Equialization.

Comment: from where to download the jai api, i googled and found lots of tutorials but not a single download link for the jar file